# when to use minmaxscaler to re-scale input data (LSTM, KERAS)

Tags: keras, lstm

My smallest value in my training dataset is 0.1 and my highest is about 500. my dataset is made about 1500 row and 09 columns.

I'm not sur about that but, is it mandatory to rescale the input data into [0,1] (wiht minmaxscaler for exemple), or is it just to speed the training ?

and second question, is this scaling is du to the model used (LSTM, DENSE, etc.) or does it work for anyone ? For example, my système is :

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(12,12),return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'))
model.add(LSTM(10,return_sequences=False,activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(5))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX, trainY, epochs=100, batch_size=1, verbose=2)
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info)

Comment: I am voting to keep this open since just changing my scalar from standard to minimax is resulting my errors to drop by more than an order of magnitude (from 0.3 t0 0.009) while everything else in the model in unchanged. Any advice appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

Scaling your data for ML is done for all types of applications. It's meant to help the model converge faster. You can check out [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/all-about-feature-scaling-bcc0ad75cb35) for a detailed explanation as to the benefits of feature scaling.

There are different ways you can scale the data, such as min-max or standard scaling; both of which are applicable for your model. If you know you have a fixed min and max in your dataset (e.g. images), you can use min-max scaling to fix your input and/or output data to be between 0 and 1.

For other applications where you do not have fixed bounds, standard scaling is useful. This gives all of your features zero-mean and unit variance. Therefore, the distributions of inputs and/or outputs are the same, and the model can treat them as such. If there is no scaling performed, the model will essentially be forced to think certain features are more important than others, rather than being able to learn those things.

The scaling for your outputs is important in defining the activation function for the output layer. If you have min-max scaled outputs, you can use `sigmoid`, because it bounds the outputs to between 0 and 1. If you are using standard scaling for the outputs, you would want to be sure you use a `linear` activation function, because *technically* standard-scaled outputs are not bounded. The choice of output activation is important, and knowledge of how your outputs are scaled is important in determining which activation to use.

Note: even if you had min-max scaling for your outputs, that does not restrict the activations you can use for your hidden layers.